# To find the new records in two days in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, union

i am checking the changed leaves from two tables using the query :-

```
with present_day 
as
(
select 1 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 9 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 2 as emp_id,'Privilege Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 3 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 5 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 10 as net_entitlement from dual
),
yester_day
as
(
select 1 as emp_id,'Sick Leave' as code , 10 as net_entitlement from dual
union
select 2 as emp_id,'Privilege Leave' as code , 5 as net_entitlement from dual
union
SELECT 3 AS EMP_ID,'Sick Leave' AS CODE , 6 AS NET_ENTITLEMENT FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 4 AS EMP_ID,'Sick Leave' AS CODE , 6 AS NET_ENTITLEMENT FROM DUAL
)

select a.emp_id,a.code,
a.net_entitlement
from present_day a,
YESTER_DAY B
WHERE A.EMP_ID=B.EMP_ID
AND A.CODE=B.CODE
and a.net_entitlement<>b.net_entitlement
```

In this query those details are coming which are changed but i need those rows also which exist in yesterday and not in present day or vice versa... how to go about it ?

The above query gives the output :-

```
emp_id  code          net_entitlement
1     Sick Leave            9
3     Sick Leave            5
```

Required output is :

```
emp_id  code          net_entitlement
1   Sick Leave  9
3   Sick Leave  5
4   Sick Leave  6
5   Sick Leave  10
```

i Tried using Union but the performance will get affected if i use :-

```
UNION 
select a.emp_id,a.code,
a.net_entitlement
from present_day a,
YESTER_DAY B
WHERE A.EMP_ID NOT IN B.EMP_ID
or B.EMP_ID NOT IN A.EMP_ID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same idea as Lennart (or at least the first version of his answer), but you need to coalesce the value in the select list as well:

```
...
select coalesce(a.emp_id, b.emp_id) as emp_id,
  coalesce(a.code, b.code) as code,
  coalesce(a.net_entitlement, b.net_entitlement) as net_entitlement
from present_day a
full outer join yester_day b
on a.emp_id = b.emp_id
and a.code = b.code
where a.net_entitlement is null
or b.net_entitlement is null
or a.net_entitlement <> b.net_entitlement;

    EMP_ID CODE            NET_ENTITLEMENT
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 Sick Leave                    9 
         3 Sick Leave                    5 
         4 Sick Leave                    6 
         5 Sick Leave                   10
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33713).

The full outer join includes records that are in either or both tables; the `where` clause excludes those that are in both with the same `net_entitlement` value. (I prefer to check for null explicitly rather than relying on a magic number even if -1 looks likely to be safe here).

Comment: its taking too much time for table which has records more than 100

Comment: 100 rows should still be trivial; so should thousands. How many rows are there in your real tables, and are they both indexed on `emp_id, code`? You probably need to look at the execution plan to see what it's doing, and if it isn't using an index you expect it to.

Comment: I am fetching from an archive table which has 10 days history...... and its taking 11 min to execute completely @Alex Poole

Comment: @user3809240 - you need to look at the execution plan to see if it's doing something unexpected.

Comment: I am sorry but did not get the meaning of execution plan ? In what way ?

Comment: The query is working absolutely right but taking time

Comment: @user3809240 - that's a lager topic than can be covered here; [start with this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like (untested):

```
select a.* from
from present_day a
left join YESTER_DAY B
   on A.EMP_ID=B.EMP_ID
  AND A.CODE=B.CODE
where a.net_entitlement<>coalesce(b.net_entitlement,-1)
union all
select b.*
from present_day a
right join YESTER_DAY B
   on A.EMP_ID=B.EMP_ID
  AND A.CODE=B.CODE
where coalesce(a.net_entitlement,-1)<>b.net_entitlement
```

Comment: @Alex solution is way better, stick with that one. I'll leave this one anyhow.